# Check if $(0,0)$ is a local min or local max

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Let $f(y,z)=y^3+zy+z^3$. Is $(0,0)$ a local min or max? For this I tried using the 2nd derivative test:

$$D=f_{xx}\cdot f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2=36xy-1^2$$

Inserting $(0,0)$:

$$36\cdot 0 \cdot 0-1^2=-1<0$$

Therefore it is a saddle point. How do I use this to see if it is local min or max? Do I need to do something different?

Comment: $f(y,0) = y^3$, so there are points arbitrarily close to $(0,0)$ that are positive and negative, so it cannot be a local $\max,\min$. It is a good idea to draw a picture before bringing in the big guns.

Comment: So it is not a max nor a min? That just seemed abit weird for me considering that I need to determine whether or not it is max or min.

Comment: Just plot $y \mapsto y^3$. What is weird about it? Note that the second derivative (at $(0,0)$) has eigenvalues $\pm 1$. A saddle point **cannot** be a local $\max, \min$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(0,0)$ is a saddle point, then it isn't a local min nor max.

Note that $f(0,z) = z^3$. Then, for every $\delta >0$, there exist $z_1, z_2 \in B_{\delta}(0)$ with $z_1 <0 <z_2$ such that $f(0,z_1) < f(0,0) < f(0,z_2)$. Therefore, $(0,0)$ is not local min nor max.

Answer (score 0):

> Inserting $(0,0)$:
>
> $$36\cdot 0 \cdot 0-1^2=-1<0$$
>
> Therefore it is a saddle point. How do I use this to see if it is local min or max?

Note- A point $P(x,y)$ can be a point of maxima, minima or a saddle point and all three cases are ***mutually exclusive***.